# Elastic Search Filter on the result of terms aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Apply Match phrase prefix query on the result of terms aggregation in Elastic Search.

I have terms query and the result looks something like below

**"buckets": [
{
"key": "KEY",
"count": 20
},
{
"key": "LOCK",
"count": 30
}
]**

Now the requirement is to filter those buckets whose key starts with a certain prefix, so something similar to match phrase prefix. For example if input to match phrase prefix query is "LOC", then only one bucket should be returned(2nd one). So effectively it's a filter on terms aggregation. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [include parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values) on your terms aggregation to filter out the values based on regex.

Something like this should work:

```
GET stackoverflow/_search
{
  "_source": false,
  "aggs": {
    "groups": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "text.keyword",
        "include": "LOC.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Example:** Let's say you have three different documents with three different terms(**LOCK**, **KEY** & **LOL**) in an index. So if you perform the following request:

```
GET stackoverflow/_search
{
  "_source": false,
  "aggs": {
    "groups": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "text.keyword",
        "include": "L.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll get the following buckets:

```
"buckets" : [
    {
      "key" : "LOCK",
      "doc_count" : 1
    },
    {
      "key" : "LOL",
      "doc_count" : 1
    }
]
```

Hope it is helpful.